# Legend stylings

Tags: python, matplotlib

One on the nuances of legend stylings is that with the histogram legend call, such as:

```
axHistogram.legend(loc='upper left', prop={'family':'serif', 'size':'x-small'}, frameon=False)
```

We have boxes rather than lines.

Also, with the scatter legend styling, we have three dots offset:

```
 axHistogram.legend(loc='upper left', prop={'family':'serif', 'size':'x-small'}, frameon=False)
```

Here is a image of what I mean:

[image]

How do I style these so that I have lines rather than boxes and just one dot rather than three offset?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [proxy artists](http://matplotlib.org/users/legend_guide.html#creating-artists-specifically-for-adding-to-the-legend-aka-proxy-artists) to create the legend entries you want, for example remove the `label=` keyword from your call to `hist`, and do something like,

```
axHistogram.plot(np.NaN, np.NaN, label='AGN', color='b', linewidth=1)
```

Then when you create your legend the entry will be a line rather than a box.

You can use the `numpoints` and `scatterpoints` input option to `legend` to control the number of points that are in the legend.

Comment: Clever. What about the scatter legend?

Comment: Use the `scatterpoints=1` input option to `axHistogram.legend`.